# Double exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

Is the following equality true?

$$\sum_i\sum_ja^{ij}\frac{x^iy^j}{i!j!}=e^{x+y}\sum_{i}\sum_j\frac{a^{ij}}{i!j!} $$
where $a$ is not $i,j$-dependent.

Comment: Where is this from? Why do you think it's (not) true? Please add more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. The LHS is $e^{a(x+y)}$, and the RHS is $e^{x+y+2a}$.